# Does android-SDK depend on android-NDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk

I have very small HDD, and android-NDK is about 3.4G in size!
Does Android-SDK depend on NDK ? 
Can I safely remove NDK without any problems ?

ps: I do not develop in C/C++, but maybe SDK somehow contacts NDK behind the scene ?

Comment: There is no dependency relationship between SDK and NDK. But if you use JNI, you will need NDK to input specified command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such depedency to NDK from SDK.
NDK is required only for apps/games development in C/C++ language.
You can safely delete NDK if you don't need it.